# Get text from text file and use for backup file name - ROBOCOPY

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

I am having a ROBOCOPY script file which looks like the following:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%_%DD%.%MM%.%YYYY%"

robocopy C:\xampp.new\htdocs D:\Backups\Registify.net\%datestamp% /MIR /s /XD dirs PROJECTS /mot:5
```

It just sets through the variable 'datestamp' the current date and time and uses it as the name of the through it created backup. Since I have more than 1 project and always changing the file structure of the source folder, I want to save the project name in a text file into the source folder, read that out through ROBOCOPY and prepend it to the destinated backup name.

The text file would look like this and is saved unter backup.name.txt in every project's folder e.g.:

```
meintatenreich
```

while the backup name should look like this in the end:

```
meintatenreich_20-47-21_13.10.2018
```

Comment: So what is stopping you from putting the contents of the text file into a variable to use with Robocopy?

Comment: @Squashman Like in every project is a backup.name.txt with the project name and if I change the project, the robocopy file would always just save the source folder as a backup with the current date and time. Now if I make huge loads of backups every 5 minutes while changing the project at some points, I would lose the overview which backup is for which project. That's why I want to dynamically read out the name of the project from the source folder's backup.name.txt for minimal expenditure

Comment: `<backup.name.txt set /p project=`. I suggest using another date/time format: `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` (or `YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss` if you prefer). That makes it sortable by the date/time string.

Comment: @Stephan That looks like what I was looking for. How should I implement this now? Could you maybe write an answer with the correct implementation? I have just found about ROBOCOPY today and really am a newbie on this

Comment: @Stephan Okay no problem i got it. Works fine, thank you alot my friend!

Comment: So your problem really had nothing to do with robocopy. Essentially what you were trying to do in its simplest form is to read the contents of a file. Which is what my first comment alluded to. You have to learn to break down your tasks into smaller chunks .